# posting to aweber with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to post to aweber using just jquery.  I have a method call like this

```
$(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                $.post('http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl',
                {
                    meta_web_form_id: '12345',
                    meta_split_id: '',
                    listname: 'some_list',
                    redirect: '',
                    meta_redirect_onlist: '',
                    meta_adtracking: 'my_Web_Form',
                    meta_message: '1',
                    meta_required: 'name,email',
                    meta_forward_vars: '',
                    meta_tooltip: '',
                    email : 'test@happy.com',
                    name : 'tester testing'
                },
                function (data) {
                    alert('data load: ' + data);
                });
            });
        });
```

it is supposed to take the result of the post and alert it in a box.  when i try to do it manually with forms it works but redirects me to a 'form-sorry.htm' page, which is fine, just wondering if there was a way to display the end result of the post.  Im guessing hte addlead.pl is just a posting page with no response.

Comment: I take it your code is not running on www.aweber.com?

Answer (score 3):

Your `$.post()` data looks okay but since you're attaching a click handler to your submit button, the form will still function normally and redirect. The data is also being sent via `$.post()` at the same time.

Here I'm using jQuery `.submit()` and grabbing the name and email values dynamically to be used in the `$.post()` method. I then clear the form by resetting it, display a confirmation message to the user, and `return false;` to prevent the normal form functionality.

For displaying the end result you can always do `alert(data);` before the `return false;` but it will show as an object, so you'd have to work with that.

You could also check the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools for your post and the data being sent.

Hope this helps.

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
    var nameVal = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var emailVal = $('input[name="email"]').val();

    $.post('http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl', {
        meta_web_form_id:   '123456789',
        meta_split_id:      '',
        listname:           'listNameHere',
        redirect:           '',
        meta_adtracking:    'newsletter',
        meta_message:       '1',
        meta_required:      'name,email',
        meta_tooltip:       '',
        name:               nameVal,
        email:              emailVal
    });

    $('#form_id')[0].reset();

    alert('Email sent!');

    return false;
});
```